# How to allow column overflow in itext pdfTable

Tags: java, itext

I have a PdfPTable with 3 columns. All columns have their width. How to allow a column to overflow to the next column when I want to add text in that column which is longer than the column width?

I want to achieve this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See figure 4.6 in iText in Action - Second Edition; it shows the result of this example:
http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=81
Look for the line where it says: cell.setNoWrap(true);

Comment: wow thx a lot I dont believe that it will be so easy.